# Dots in object keys

Tags: javascript

This has probably been asked before but I couldn't find any threads.

I have an object with constants that I want to use as keys in a list of objects:

```
//CONSTANTS.Foo === 1
//CONSTANTS.Bar === 2
var list = [{ CONSTANTS.Foo: 'foo' }, { CONSTANTS.Bar: 'bar' }];
```

This is obviously an invalid syntax. How should I solve this? I'm thinking about Array.map(), but I would like your input.

http://jsfiddle.net/wKYe6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have an object literal with dynamic keys, you need to add the properties after object initialization :

```
var o, list = [];
o = {}; o[CONSTANTS.Foo] = 'foo'; list.push(o);
o = {}; o[CONSTANTS.Bar] = 'bar'; list.push(o);
```

Of course if you have some kind of known relation between constants and values, you may automate this construction or make it dryer.

You might also do this :

```
var list = [{ Foo: 'foo' }, { Bar: 'bar' }].map(function(o){
  for (var k in o) {
     o[Constants[k]]=o[k];
     delete o[k]; 
  }
  return o;
});
```

Comment: Meh, I was hoping it was doable in another way. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor function first:

```
function Obj(propertyName, value) {
    this[propertyName] = value;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var list = [new Obj(CONSTANTS.Foo, 'foo'), new Obj(CONSTANTS.Bar, 'bar')]
```

Your [jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/wKYe6/1/)